How to setup citation style [Doe, 2024] and for multiple authors [DBK, 2000]?
Im looking for a way to implement the following citation style into my article:

single author sources -> [Lastname, year]
multiple author sources -> [Firstletterofauthor1Firstletterofauthor2Firstletterofauthor3, year]

So far i have only found the alphabetic style to implement the single author citation.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,maxalphanames=1]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
    \labelelement{
        \field[final]{shorthand}
        \field{labelname}
        \field{label}
    }
    \labelelement{
        \literal{,\addhighpenspace}
    }
    \labelelement{
        \field{year}
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \cite{knuth:ct:b,baez/article,baez/online}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}

As mentioned before. This style works perfectly fine for single author sources.
In the example: [Knuth, 1986]
But for the second source only a + is added for multiple authors.
In this case it should be [BL, 2004a]
How to setup the citation style to implement the first letters?

Welcome! Does the style have a name? Or is it required by a journal or organisation? It's sometimes possible to find styles that way: if you have to do this, chances are somebody else has had to do it before.

Thanks for the hint. It is for a masterthesis and the requierements from the department I am writing for differ from the general template of the university. Therefore it is not standardized.  So far everyone in the department has written the theisis in word.

Sorry to hear that ;).

You may want to try the following.
The key ingredient is the ifnames=1, which lets you treat the single-author case differently from all the others.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  style=alphabetic,
  maxalphanames=3, minalphanames=3,
  maxbibnames=999,
]{biblatex}


\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field{label}
    \field[ifnames=1]{labelname}
    \field[strwidth=1,strside=left,noalphaothers=true]{labelname}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \literal{,\addhighpenspace}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field{year}
  }
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
  \cite{knuth:ct:b,baez/article,baez/online,companion,aksin}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}



Thank you very much for this answer. This worked absolutely fine.
